# It's possible to set Saved Search Result column in dashboard same size/weigth?

Tags: netsuite, dashboard, saved-searches

I want to display the result of 4 saved searchs on a dashboard with the same display format.
they have the same number of columns but the are displayed differently .

can I change this behaviour ?

[image]

Comment: Does the top saved search have any highlighting with bold set to true in the search definition?

Comment: No nothing the only difference between both , is one is filter to mainline is true (second one ) and the top one , mainline to false so I grouped the result

Comment: I think you'd have to create a custom portlet (Portlet script type) to be able to control the column width.  The NEtSuite Portlet Object does not seem to have properties/methods that control width.  So you'd have to go full blown custom HTML to get the data from saved searches and display them how you'd like.  Ref Suite Answer 43796